# flask image not displaying using img tag

Tags: flask

I am trying to display an image that is not in static folder but inside a logos folder.

The folder where my app.py is situated is this

app.py
static
logos <--- I want to access image from this folder.

```
{% for company in companies %}
          {% if company.logo %}
            <img src="/logos/{{company.logo}}" width="200" height="85"/>
          {% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

In HTML inspect element it comes properly as

```
<img src="/logos/59a94931df425f3034d2.jpg" width="200" height="85">
```

The file actually exists but the image is not displayed in webpage

Answer (score 0):

The `logos` directory must be inside the `static` directory, in order to allow python to find the image and return that to the browser. In fact, if you check the console, you will see error 404: Not Found

So, put `logos` directory inside `static` and replace the url with:

```
src="logos/logos/{{company.logo}}.jpg"
```

Another way could be using `url_for` function (always inside your html file):

```
{{url_for('static', filename = f'logos/{company.logo}')}}
```

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what barbax has said, but your images to be rendered need to be within a static folder, and give this as the root directory when providing the path in html, e.g if this is your folder structure:

```
<ROOT>
  └── app
       └── static
           └── logos
```

This should be your `src` value:

```html
src='static/logos/{{ company.logo }}'
```